# how replicate only the user's documents

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I need to sync some document from Cloudant server to my iOS in swift language.
For that I use this official library

https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore#overview

I need to understand how replicate only user documents.
I need to figure out the correct road.

Imagine you a ticket assistance system of a company.

All users can create the ticket and this is save in cloudant/couchdb server.
When the user uses a mobile platform, I would just like to synchronize him ticket 
how can I do it?

Thank all

Answer (score 0):

CDTDatastore is designed to sync the whole database, and cloudant/ couchdb doesn't provide a per document ACL. In order to only sync a specific users data you either need to use a filter function, which will significantly hit the performance of the replication, or use the one database per user model.

Comment: One database for every users? This is much expensive. How can use the filters? I don't want replicate all document..:

Comment: @DanieleGrillo You create a filter function as per the docs here: https://docs.cloudant.com/advanced_replication.html#filtered-replication and you provide the information for the filter function on the replication in CDTDatastore